# Change value of data-list inside an Input tag

Tags: javascript, html-input

I want to change the value of the 'data-list' attribute here :

```
<input id="Searchbar" data-list="Javascript,Css,Test" data-multiple/>
```

I tried :

```
Document.getElementById('Searchbar').XXXXX
```

All this stuff but I can't find the right way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `document.getElementById('Searchbar').setAttribute('data-list', 'value')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `document` is case sensitive. Try:

```
document.getElementById('Searchbar').XXXXX
```

And to set the `data-list` attribute, you need to do:

```
document.getElementById('Searchbar').setAttribute("data-list", "new,list");
```